# Data Table to Div Output

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, datatable

Bit of a beginner here.

I have a data table with 3 columns. MessageID, MessageSubject and MessageBody. Data has 15 rows.

Data is returning as expected. I would like to get this on the page each subject and message in their own divs in a specific area on the page.

1. I don't know how to write the divs out in a loop.

2.I don't know how to feed that back to a specific area on teh page.

I am using vb.net in Visual Basic.

Thanks all.

Comment: This might help you get started: [How to: Add a Repeater Control to a Web Forms Page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zzx23804(v=vs.85).aspx). Pretty much you put the repeater where you want the content shown, and add your divs in the `ItemTemplate`.

Comment: You can also use `.innerHTML` and `.innerText` on an element that has the `runat="server"` attribute.